# I want to display clickedcellvalue name in my visualforce page but I am getting a null string

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have an assignment to complete and its urgent.. So any help would be appreciated..
[image: Assignment]

Here is my attempt:

My Vf Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="account" extensions="accsearchcontroller" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">  
  <apex:form >  
    <apex:inputtext value="{!searchString}" id="thesearch" />
  <apex:commandButton value="Search records" action="{!search}"/>  

   <apex:actionFunction name="readCell" action="{!readCellMethod}">
    <apex:param name="P2" value="" assignTo="{!clickedCellValue}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
   <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="tableContainer" layout="block">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="item" title="Contact List"  >
                <apex:column value="{!item.name}" onclick="readCell('{!item.name}',name)"/>
                <apex:column value="{!item.id}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
     <apex:outputtext value="{0}">
     <apex:param value="{!clickedCellValue}"/>
     </apex:outputtext>
  <apex:commandButton value="submit" id="submitButton" reRender="thesearch"/>
  </apex:form>  
 </apex:page>
```

my Controller class:

```
public with sharing class accsearchcontroller {  
   public List<account> acc {get;set;}  
   public List<Contact> contacts {get;set;}
  public String clickedCellValue { get; set; } 

   public accsearchcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {  
   }  
   public void search(){  
     string searchquery='select name,id from account where name like \'%'+searchstring+'%\' Limit 20';  
     acc= Database.query(searchquery);  
   }  
    public string searchstring {get;set;}

    public PageReference readCellMethod(){
    System.debug('#### clickedCellValue: ' + clickedCellValue);
    return null;
}

   public void clear(){  
   acc.clear();  
   }  
 }
```

Comment: Can you give us some more info about where you're getting the error etc?

Answer (score 1):

You need to work more with standard objects of salesforce. The list of contacts can be easily implemented using visualforce tag `apex:relatedList`. And a search functionallity just using a standard Account lookup relation from some standard object (a Contact for example).

Here is a controller. To be able to search for accounts i will take a standard object Contact that have an Account reference by default. This will be just a dummy object used only for referencing on the page. After user selects an account we will have an Account ID. Then the only thing we need to do is to assign that ID to the page. The page used an Account as a  standard controller, so we can easily access it related lists just by name.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class SearchAccount {  

    public Contact dummyContact { get; set; }

    public SearchAccount (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        dummyContact = new Contact();
    }

    public void searchAccount(){  
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', dummyContact.AccountId);
    }  
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="SearchAccount">

<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock title="Search for Account">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!searchAccount}" reRender="contacts"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:inputField value="{!dummyContact.AccountId}" />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

<apex:outputPanel id="contacts">
    <apex:relatedList list="Contacts" />
</apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```

So the step 1 will look like this (no account selected):

[image]

And after user selects an account the related list will appear:

[image]